# Multi-tenancy using single database multiple schema with Hibernate and Spring Boot saving data to wrong schema

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I am trying to seed my multiple tenant (single database, multiple schemas) system with data but running into an issue that wasn't present when I was using the same code with a single database. I fully expect during my research that I have missed something obvious.

Each schema will contain the exact same table structure.

Here is my Tenant Context

```
public class TenantContext {

    public static final String DEFAULT_TENANT_IDENTIFIER = "public";

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> TENANT_IDENTIFIER = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setTenant(String tenantIdentifier) {
        TENANT_IDENTIFIER.set(tenantIdentifier);
    }

    public static void reset(String tenantIdentifier) {
        TENANT_IDENTIFIER.remove();
    }

    @Component
    public static class TenantIdentifierResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {
        @Override
        public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
            String currentTenantId = TENANT_IDENTIFIER.get();
            return currentTenantId != null ?
                    currentTenantId :
                    DEFAULT_TENANT_IDENTIFIER;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And my HibernateConfig

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
             MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider, CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver) {

        Map<String, Object> jpaPropertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
        jpaPropertiesMap.putAll(jpaProperties.getProperties());
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProvider);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, TenantContext.TenantIdentifierResolver.class);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(UppStudentAppBeApplication.class.getPackage().getName());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertiesMap);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

And my TenantConenctionProvider

```
@Component
public class TenantConnectionProvider implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TenantConnectionProvider.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public TenantConnectionProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
        logger.info("Get connection for tenant  " + String.join(":", tenantIdentifier ));
        final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
        try {
            //connection.createStatement().execute( String.format("SET SCHEMA \"%s\";", tenantIdentifier));
            connection.setSchema(tenantIdentifier);
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                    "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" +
                            tenantIdentifier + "]",
                    e
            );
        }
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            //connection.createStatement().execute( String.format("SET SCHEMA \"%s\";", TenantContext.DEFAULT_TENANT_IDENTIFIER) );
            connection.setSchema(TenantContext.DEFAULT_TENANT_IDENTIFIER);
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                    "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" +
                            tenantIdentifier + "]",
                    e
            );
        }
        releaseAnyConnection(connection);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I call my seeding class that builds out my tenants and schemas using flyway migration.

I then try to loop through the saved tenants switching the TenantContext. Which when debugging appears to work. However when I try and do anything with the repo I get the following error.

> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column campus0_.createdat does not exist
> Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "campus0_.created_at".
> Position: 32

As I said earlier this worked fine previously when it was a single database and schema. I am not 100% sure on where I have gone wrong. Am I supposed to register the schemas some how? If so how can I onboard new tenants without redeploying? Should I use a custom query at this stage that uses the schema in the repo?

Thank you in advance for any help or advice.

**EDIT 1**
So I have now got past my initial hurdle by checking the hibernate properties so by changing the hibernate config as follows

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
             MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider,
             HibernateProperties hibernateProperties) {

        Map<String, Object> jpaPropertiesMap = hibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(jpaProperties.getProperties(), new HibernateSettings());
        //jpaPropertiesMap.putAll(jpaProperties.getProperties());
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProvider);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, TenantContext.TenantIdentifierResolver.class);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(UppStudentAppBeApplication.class.getPackage().getName());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertiesMap);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}
```

This has now removed the above naming error. However now it is saving to my default schema rather than the schema set in the TenantIdentifierResolver.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented `AsyncHandlerInterceptor` - interceptor of Spring. Should be registered also in `WebMvcConfigurer`.

```
@Component
public class TenantRequestInterceptor implements AsyncHandlerInterceptor{

private SecurityDomain securityDomain;

public TenantRequestInterceptor(SecurityDomain securityDomain) {
    this.securityDomain = securityDomain;
}

 @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
     return Optional.ofNullable(request)
             .map(req -> securityDomain.getTenantIdFromJwt(req))
             .map(tenant -> setTenantContext(tenant))
             .orElse(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        TenantContext.reset();
    }
    
    private boolean setTenantContext(String tenant) {
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(tenant);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is important, because here you fill TenantContext with tenant.
Have you debuged method `getConnection(String tenantIdentifier)`  what value is as tenantIdentifier?